# .net windows authentication - strange issue after user change AD account

Tags: windows-authentication

I have a project with windows authentication and everything works fine. The issue i am having is with a specific user that had his AD account changed.

After account change he hasn't be able to log in. Looked into his ad account and everything looks the same as mine.

The strange thing is it worked fine in the localhost. I also haven't made any change to the IIS if that helps.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to recycle the pool to create the cache for LSA lookup cache, if you can't recycle the pool you can do the following:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946358

Found it here:

[IIS Returning Old User Names to my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168946/iis-returning-old-user-names-to-my-application)